# Date_add function returning None

Tags: python, pyspark, hiveql, dateadd

I have a column in a `dataframe1` that has date `today_date` and i have another `dataframe2` that has `days` along with other columns.. I am converting these two dataframes into a temptable

I need to join `dataframe1` with `dataframe2` on one column and then add `today_date` with `days`. I am using `sqlcontext` to query these two temp tables

I am currently using `date_add` function.

```
sqlcontext.sql("select date_add(today_date,days) as 'Future_date' from dataframe1 x1 join dataframe2 x2 on x1.a=x2.a"
```

However, it is returning None value in the future_date. The hive version that am using is pretty old... am running this code in `pyspark`...

Any help is much appreciated..

Note: I converted the `days` function from `unicode` to `int` using

```
dataframe2['days']=dataframe2['days'].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what went wrong without a sample dataframe... Maybe `today_date` is not of type `DateType` (it's a `StringType` perhaps?).

Here's a quick example to test your code which works:

```py
from datetime import date
sc.parallelize([[m, date(2017, m, 1)] for m in range(1, 11)]).toDF(["a", "today_date"]).registerTempTable("dataframe1")
sc.parallelize([[m, 10*m] for m in range(10)]).toDF(["a", "days"]).registerTempTable("dataframe2")
```

I used `SQLContext` here because it doesn't have all the functions `HiveContext` has so it's usually the most problematic. However the code works fine for `HiveContext` and `spark.sql` (in Spark 2):

```py
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlcontext = SQLContext(sc)
sqlcontext.sql("select date_add(today_date,days) as Future_date from dataframe1 x1 join dataframe2 x2 on x1.a=x2.a").show()

    +-----------+
    |Future_date|
    +-----------+
    | 2017-09-09|
    | 2017-07-31|
    | 2017-11-30|
    | 2017-06-20|
    | 2017-01-11|
    | 2017-03-31|
    | 2017-10-20|
    | 2017-02-21|
    | 2017-05-11|
    +-----------+
```